# How to address and avoid mixed ownership of .git/objects objects when using Docker with git?

Tags: docker

I'm working on a git project that has a Dockerfile. When I run ls -l in the .git/objects repo, some of the "xx" directories are owned by me, with permissions 777, and some of the "xx" directories are owned by root, with permissions 755.

When I look into the directories owned by me, some or all of the hashed files will be owned by me with 777 permissions, and maybe some owned by root, with 444 permissions. When I look into the directories owned by root, all of the hashed files are owned by root with 444 permissions.

It seems that I might have run my container with root as container's user, which is why I get root as file owner in some parts of my repository.

I want to use Docker to help run and manage my code, but clearly the way I was using it was causing problems. Do I just need to run Docker as my normal user? If I ran all my git operations outside of the Dockerized terminal, that would probably avoid this as well, right? Or is there something else I can or should do?

Thanks for any and all feedback/advice

Comment: This is, by and large, a Docker issue. Git is pretty much incidental: you'd have the same problem with any other program.

Comment: I'd suggest running `git` exclusively on your host system.  There are various things that make it hard to manage running it in a Dockerfile; trying to replace the code of a running process usually doesn't work and isn't Docker's standard model.  (Mode 0777 – any user can read, write, or execute any file, and therefore anyone can overwrite an executable someone else is using – is almost always incorrect.)